# ISR executes twice if data coming through SoftwareSerial

Tags: interrupt, softwareserial, arduino-pro-mini, isr

I am using Arduino Pro Mini to get GPS info from a u-blox NEO-M8N chip and display it on a Adafruit OLED display. NEO-M8N has a PPS(pulse per second) output which is aligned to GPS's second. Because UART and deserialization is slow, I use PPS signal to make time displays more accurately. The PPS(time pulse) signal and UART message are coming like this:

[image: TIMEPULSE and Serial Data]

On my Arduino, SoftwareSerial RX/TX is on pin 7/8 (but only use pin 7 because Arduino has no message to send to NEO-M8N), and the interrupt(PPS) is on pin 2. If I just connect pin 7, display update once per second as intended; if I just connect pin 2, time increased by one second per second as intended. BUT if connect them both, `((`time will increased more than one second per second`)` and `(` `processGPS()` will lost sync with upcoming UBX(u-blox message format) message`))` occasionally.

And here is the entire code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 9
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

#if (SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT != 64)
#error("Height incorrect, please fix Adafruit_SSD1306.h!");
#endif


// Connect the GPS RX/TX to arduino pins 7 and 8
SoftwareSerial S_Serial = SoftwareSerial(7,8);
int intpin = 2;
volatile int state = LOW;

const unsigned char UBX_HEADER[] = { 0xB5, 0x62 };

struct NAV_PVT {
  unsigned char cls;
  unsigned char id;
  unsigned short len;
  unsigned long iTOW;
  unsigned short year;
  byte month;
  byte day;
  byte hour;
  byte miniute;
  byte sec;
  unsigned char valid;
  unsigned long tAcc;
  long nano;
  byte fixType;
  unsigned char flag;
  unsigned char flag2;
  byte numSV;
  long lon;
  long lat;
  long height;
  long hMSL;
  unsigned long hAcc;
  unsigned long vAcc;
  long velN;
  long velE;
  long velD;
  long gSpeed;
  long headMot;
  unsigned long sAcc;
  unsigned long headAcc;
  unsigned short pDop;
  byte reserved1[6];
  long headVeh;
  byte reserved2[4];
};

NAV_PVT pvt;

void calcChecksum(unsigned char* CK) {
  memset(CK, 0, 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(NAV_PVT); i++) {
    CK[0] += ((unsigned char*)(&pvt))[i];
    CK[1] += CK[0];
  }
}

bool processGPS() {
  static int fpos = 0;
  static unsigned char checksum[2];
  const int payloadSize = sizeof(NAV_PVT);

  while ( S_Serial.available() ) {
    byte c = S_Serial.read();
    if ( fpos < 2 ) { //SYNC
      if ( c == UBX_HEADER[fpos] )
        fpos++;
      else
        fpos = 0;
    }
    else {
      if ( (fpos-2) < payloadSize )
        ((unsigned char*)(&pvt))[fpos-2] = c;

      fpos++;

      if ( fpos == (payloadSize+2) ) {
        calcChecksum(checksum);
      }
      else if ( fpos == (payloadSize+3) ) {
        if ( c != checksum[0] )
          fpos = 0;
      }
      else if ( fpos == (payloadSize+4) ) {
        fpos = 0;
        if ( c == checksum[1] ) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      else if ( fpos > (payloadSize+4) ) {
        fpos = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

void pps()
{
  state=!state;
}

void PrintScreen()
{
  display.clearDisplay();

  //Size 2
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0,0);
  float sik = (pvt.gSpeed / 100) / 3.6f;
  if (sik<100)
    display.print(" ");
  if (sik<10)
    display.print(" ");
  display.print(sik,1);//SpeedInKph
  display.setCursor(84,0);
  if (pvt.numSV<10)
    display.print(" ");
  display.print(pvt.numSV);//SV

  //Size 1
  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setCursor(60,8);
  display.print("km/h");
  display.setCursor(63,0);
  display.print("CHL");
  display.setCursor(108,8);
  display.print("SVs");
  display.setCursor(108,0);
  switch (pvt.fixType){
    case 0:
      display.print("N.F");
      break;
    case 2:
      display.print("2D");
      break;
    case 3:
      display.print("3D");
      if ((byte)pvt.flag & 2)
        display.print("+");
      break;
    default:
      display.print("INV");
      break;
  }



  long  temp;
  //Line 1
  display.setCursor(0,16);
  if (pvt.lat >= 0)
    temp = pvt.lat;
  else
    temp = -pvt.lat;
  if (temp >= 1000000000)
    display.print("lat:");
  else 
    if (temp >= 100000000)
      display.print("lat: ");
    else
      display.print("lat:  ");
  display.print(temp / 10000000);display.print(".");
  long temp2 = 1000000;
  temp = temp % 10000000;
  while ((temp / temp2 == 0)&&(temp2>1))
  {
    display.print("0");
    temp2 /= 10;
  }
  display.print(temp);
  if (pvt.lat >= 0)
    display.print("N");
  else
    display.print("S");
  temp = 10000;
  while (((pvt.pDop / temp) == 0)&&(temp>1))
  {
    display.print(" ");
    temp /= 10;
  }
  display.println(pvt.pDop);

  //Line2
  if (pvt.lon >= 0)
    temp = pvt.lon;
  else
    temp = -pvt.lon;
  if (temp >= 1000000000)
    display.print("lon:");
  else 
    if (temp >= 100000000)
      display.print("lon: ");
    else
      display.print("lon:  ");
  display.print(temp / 10000000);display.print(".");
  temp2 = 1000000;
  temp = temp % 10000000;
  while ((temp / temp2 == 0)&&(temp2>1))
  {
    display.print("0");
    temp2 /= 10;
  }
  display.print(temp);
  if (pvt.lon >= 0)
    display.print("E");
  else
    display.print("W");
  display.println(" HEAD");

  //Line3
  display.print("hMSL:");
  if (pvt.hMSL < 0)
    pvt.hMSL = -pvt.hMSL;
  temp = 10000000;
  while (((pvt.hMSL / temp) == 0)&&(temp>1000))
  {
    display.print(" ");
    temp /= 10;
  }
  display.print((pvt.hMSL % 100000000) / 1000);display.print(".");
  if ((pvt.hMSL % 1000) < 100)
    display.print("0");
  if ((pvt.hMSL % 1000) < 10)
    display.print("0");
  display.print(pvt.hMSL % 1000);
  display.print("|");
  temp = pvt.headMot / 100000;
  if (temp < 100)
    display.print(" ");
  if (temp < 10)
    display.print(" ");
  display.print(temp);display.print(".");
  temp2 = (pvt.headMot%100000)/1000;
  if (temp2<0)
    temp2 = -temp2;
  if (temp2<10)
    display.print("0");
  display.println(temp2);

  //Line4
  display.print("h,vAcc:");
  if (pvt.hAcc >= 100000)
    display.print("  >100");
  else
  {
    display.print(pvt.hAcc / 1000);display.print(".");
    if (pvt.hAcc % 1000 < 100)
      display.print("0");
    if (pvt.hAcc % 1000 < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.hAcc % 1000);
  }
  display.print(",");
  if (pvt.vAcc >= 100000)
    display.print(" >100");
  else
  {
    display.print(pvt.vAcc / 1000);display.print(".");
    if (pvt.vAcc%1000 < 100)
      display.print("0");
    if (pvt.vAcc%1000 < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.vAcc%1000);
  }
  display.println("m");

  //Line5
  display.print("V:");
  if (pvt.gSpeed < 1000000)
    display.print(" ");
  if (pvt.gSpeed < 100000)
    display.print(" ");
  if (pvt.gSpeed < 10000)
    display.print(" ");
  display.print((pvt.gSpeed % 10000000)/1000);display.print(".");
  if (pvt.gSpeed % 1000 < 100)
    display.print("0");
  if (pvt.gSpeed % 1000 < 10)
    display.print("0");
  display.print(pvt.gSpeed % 1000);
  display.print("m/s");
  if (pvt.sAcc < 1000000)
  {
    if (pvt.sAcc < 100000)
      display.print(" ");
    if (pvt.sAcc < 10000)
      display.print(" ");
    display.print("~");
    display.print(pvt.sAcc / 1000);display.print(".");
    if (pvt.sAcc % 1000 < 100)
      display.print("0");
    if (pvt.sAcc % 1000 < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.println(pvt.sAcc % 1000);
  }
  else
  display.println(" ~>100");

  //Line6
  if ((pvt.year<10000)&&(pvt.year>=1000))
    display.print(pvt.year);
  else
    display.print("????");
  display.print("/");
  if ((pvt.month<=12)&&(pvt.month>=1))
  {
    if (pvt.month < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.month);
  }
  else
    display.print("??");
  display.print("/");
  if ((pvt.day<=31)&&(pvt.day>=1))
  {
    if (pvt.day < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.day);
  }
  else
    display.print("??");
  if (pvt.valid & 0x04)
    display.print("UTC");
  else
    display.print("INV");
  if ((pvt.hour<=23)&&(pvt.hour>=0))
  {
    if (pvt.hour < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.hour);
  }
  else
    display.print("??");
  display.print(":");
  if ((pvt.miniute<=59)&&(pvt.miniute>=0))
  {
    if (pvt.miniute < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.miniute);
  }
  else
    display.print("??");
  display.print(":");
  if ((pvt.sec<=60)&&(pvt.sec>=0))
  {
    if (pvt.sec < 10)
      display.print("0");
    display.print(pvt.sec);
  }
  else
    display.print("??");

  display.display();
}

void PrintSec()
{
  pvt.sec = (pvt.sec + 1)%60;
  display.fillRect(114,56,12,8,BLACK);
  display.setCursor(114,56);
  if (pvt.sec<10)
    display.print("0");
  display.println(pvt.sec);
  display.display();
  state = LOW;
}

void setup() 
{
  S_Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(intpin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(intpin), pps, RISING);
  // by default, we'll generate the high voltage from the 3.3v line internally! (neat!)
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);  
  // init done
}

void loop() {
  if (state == HIGH)
    PrintSec();
  if ( processGPS() ) 
    PrintScreen();
}
```

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343058/interrupt-service-routine-executes-twice-atmega88) (Interrupt Service Routine Executes Twice ATmega88), but since ISR only executes once if I connect pin 2 alone, I think the cause might be something else.

Is it a software issue or a hardware issue? How to fix it?

Comment: How can you tell that time is increased more than one second per second? You you show some of the Serial output you get on your PC?

Comment: I show the time on an oled display, [looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/9flJIhi.jpg) and the seconds was increased twice in one second sometimes, and other information on the display just froze. Normally, the lon(titude), lat(titude) and other positioning info are jittering all the time, so it is obvious when something goes wrong.

Comment: The ISR just won't be called twice from one interrupt. However your code is complex enough that what you observe is possible. For example, if `state` is HIGH, then you print the seconds, followed by reading the GPS (which also prints the seconds). This may well cause the seconds to update twice.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** First, deferring `PrintSec` to `loop` through the volatile `state`, which is set by the ISR, actually takes *more* time to update the display.  You might as well just test the pin in `loop`:

```
void setup() 
{
  S_Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(intpin, INPUT);

  // by default, we'll generate the high voltage from the 3.3v line internally! (neat!)
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);  
}

void loop() {

         bool state    = digitalRead(intPin);
  static bool oldState = false;

  // Watch for change
  if (oldState != state) {
    oldState = state;

    // RISING edge?
    if (state)
      PrintSec();
  }

  if ( processGPS() ) 
    PrintScreen();
}
```

---

**2)** "But I might miss a PPS!" you exclaim.  The bad news is that if you can't finish `PrintScreen` in time to get back to testing the pin, then you're Trying To Do Too Much.

You might want to consider incremental updates of the display.  If you have the previous pieces (i.e., an extra NAV_PVT struct), you could compare each piece to see if it has changed.  If it has, it's ok to spend time writing it.  Just add an extra test to each piece:

```
NAV_PVT pvt, prevPVT;
static bool firstTime = true;
  .
  .
  .
void PrintScreen()
{
  if (firstTime)
    display.clearDisplay();

  //Size 2
  display.setTextSize(2);
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);

  //  Update the Speed?
  if (firstTime || (pvt.gSpeed != prevPVT.gSpeed)) {
    display.setCursor(0,0);
    float sik = (pvt.gSpeed / 100) / 3.6f;
    if (sik<100)
      display.print(" ");
    if (sik<10)
      display.print(" ");
    display.print(sik,1);//SpeedInKph
  }
```

At the end of `PrintScreen`, do this:

```
  display.display();

  prevPVT   = pvt;
  firstTime = false;
}
```

For most updates, only the `seconds` field would get written.

Clearing the screen and drawing the labels could probably happen just once in `setup`.

---

**3)** I would suggest a more efficient and reliable software serial library.  `SoftwareSerial` disables *all* interrupts for the entire 10-bit character time, once the start bit is received.  This makes it both vulnerable and intrusive to other interrupts, like PinChange and SPI.  Ick.  If you can use pins 8 & 9, AltSoftSerial is the best choice.

If you can't use those pins, and you're not using the USB port to connect to a host, could you use Serial input (pin 0) for the GPS?  The GPS would have to be disconnected to do USB programming, but it could stay connected if you're using an ISP.

---

**4)** You need a more robust way to restart UBX packet framing, even if chars are lost.  I would suggest something like this:

```
void loop() {
  if (state == HIGH) {
    PrintSec();
    fpos = 0; // new packet coming soon, ditch old partial packet
  }
  if ( processGPS() ) 
    PrintScreen();
}
```

At least that will keep you in sync.  Without it, packet completion might not happen until after a 2nd PPS occurs (and 2nd packet begins arriving).  Maybe this explains the symptoms you're seeing?

Comment: I tried 3) first, and the hardware serial input works much better and never lose chars. But meanwhile, second was increased twice per second constantly. You are right, PrintSec was deferred to the loop, so the use of interrupt is meaningless. I tried 1) then, but the second still got increase twice sometimes.  I found [this article](http://gammon.com.au/interrupts), it says "Pin Change Interrupt Request 2 (pins D0 to D7)" shared the same interrupt vector, so I use pin 12 to receive PPS instead. The second will only get increase twice once every 3min now.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you have 2 ways that increase your seconds,

1. when software serial receives data
2. When PPM pin goes high

And when each of theese are run separately things work, but when you use them together seconds increase by 2 each time ?

wouldnt this suggest that your program only should use one of theese to increase your seconds.

Comment: No, I just have one way to increase my seconds, when PPS pin goes high. I GET the seconds from serial data. That is, when the PPS goes high, seconds++; when serial data comes, seconds = seconds_from_gps.

Comment: Maybe showing your complete code will clarify for us what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I just edited it.

Comment: You sure about this line: pvt.sec = (pvt.sec + 1)%60;

Comment: It increase the second by one. Use pvt.sec instead of a local variable to save some space.